# ¿Como puedo descargar el codigo de una pagina web desde una aplicacion hecha en java?

Tags: java, html

La cuestion es la siguiente, yo quisiera descargar el codigo de una pagina web desde una aplicacion hecha en JAVA, el problema surge en que cuando ingreso la url que quiero descargar, en vez de descargar esa pagina correspondiente a la URL, me descarga la pagina de LOGIN, cosa que no quiero. Tienen alguna idea de que puedo implementar para hacer esto.

Comment: Tu pregunta fue reportada de baja calidad, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**

Answer (score 0):

Ya hay una respuesta a esta pregunta, aunque está en inglés.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422970/get-source-of-website-in-java#423077

La respuesta anterior implementa sockets (SSL en el caso concreto del link provisto, dado que la página web se consulta bajo el protocolo HTTPS) para leer páginas como flujos de datos

Answer (score 0):

Para descargar (y procesar) páginas HTML yo uso [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). **Ahora bien**, si dices que has hecho algo y te está descargando una página de login significa que la URL que estás pasando está securizada y, por tanto, desde tu aplicación, tendrás que realizar el login, obtener el, probablemente, token de sesión que te generará el servidor e incluirlo en las peticiones que hagas más adelante, pero eso ya se sale completamente de la pregunta que has planteado.